# watir-webdriver --ignore-certificate-errors passed while I do not want to ignore it (Chrome)

Tags: watir-webdriver

I would like Watir to start Google Chrome without getting a message about an unsupported option '--ignore-certificate-errors'. I already tried the following too:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[]
```

The basic problem I want to solve is to do a secure automated login.

Note: this problem has already been solved. 
Using version ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) it works.

Comment: Are you using the newest versions of Chromedriver and Chrome? Updating both of those fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved by upgrading to the latest version of ChromeDriver - 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3).